# Help Aligning a Pattern with `align-regexp`

Tags: regular-expressions, align

How can I use `M-x align-regexp` to align by

1. `//`
2. All `;` after `//`
3. All `,` within `[]` after `//`

For example:

With text:

```
Line 1 ; B // Comment 1 [11, 22] ; Comment 2 [3333, 4]
Line 2 C // Comment 3 [3, 55]   ; Comment 4 [33,222]
```

How can I achieve alignment of something like

```
Line 1 ; B // Comment 1 [11, 22]; Comment 2 [3333, 4]
Line 2 C   // Comment 3 [3 , 55]; Comment 4 [33  ,222]
```

I have confirmed already that `M-x align-regexp //` aligns the `//` properly, but everything else after that is over my head :-)

Comment: I believe this wouldn't be possible with a regular expression without lookbehind. Seems like this is asking for more code than just calling to `align-regexp`.

Comment: Using `align.el` in general, it's possible to specify multiple groups of whitespace to align in one line.  But the problem is that they all have to match, otherwise an error occurs.   So, the only way I see this happening is using a custom search function as `regexp` attribute to the `align-region` function.

Comment: @politza: Can you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by the `align-region` idea?

Comment: `align-region` is the function doing the actual work, the other command is just a wrapper around it.  It allows you to specify a function as a "regexp" which then would search the appropriate strings to align and setup the match-data on which align operates.